# On click of checkbox send email to selected recipients using module

Tags: views

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function send_email(){
 var persons_names;
 persons_names = $('#send_mail_persons input:checked');
 var persons_names_Str='',coma='';
 if(persons_names.length != 0){
 persons_names.each(function(){
     persons_names_Str += coma+$(this).val();
     coma = ',';
 })
 }
 alert(persons_names_Str);
 //    console.log(" persons_names_Str: "+persons_names_Str);
 ajax_call_to_send_values_to(persons_names_Str);
 }


 function ajax_call_to_send_values_to(persons_names_Str){
 $.ajax({
              url: 'http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?  >',
            type: 'POST',
              data: { persons_names_Str: persons_names_Str            
                       },  
              success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

              },
            //called when successful

              error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //called when there is an error
                  }
    });
 }
 </script>

 <?php
 if( isset($_POST['persons_names_Str']) && !empty($_POST['persons_names_Str']) )
  {
 $list = $_POST['persons_names_Str'];
 //print_r($list);
 //$to_arr = explode(",", $list);
 //$to = array_filter($to_arr);
 //echo $to;
 //print_r($to);
 $to = $list;
 $subject = "Test Subject";
 $body = "This is temporary email from Lawandmoney. ";
 $headers = "From: no-reply@lawandmoney.com\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: php";

 $to =  "no-reply@lawandmoney.com";
 $headerFields = array('BCC: '.$list.', "From: no-reply@lawandmoney.com" ."X-Mailer:    php"');
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headerFields))) {
 //if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  echo("<p>Message sent successfully! our lawyer will contact you as soon as   possible</p>");
  } else {
  echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
  exit();
  }  

  ?>

  <div id="send_mail_persons">
  <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM lawyer_details WHERE city LIKE :city AND speciality LIKE   :speciality";
   $result = db_query($sql,array(':city' => '%'.  db_like($_SESSION['selected_county']).'%' , ':speciality' =>  '%'.db_like($_SESSION['lawarea']).'%'));

 $rows_count=$result->rowCount();

 if($result && $rows_count>0) 
 { 
 while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) 
 {
  ?>
  <div class="result">
   <div class="resultPadder">
       <div class="resultLeft">
          <div id="fav">
         <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="email1" value=<?php echo  $row['email_id'];?> /><a class="b ui-link" href="" onclick=""><?php echo  $row['first_name'].' '.$row['middle_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];?></a>  
          </div>
       <div class="p-t-2"><?php echo $row['street_address'];?></div>
       </div>
       </div>
  <div class="resultRight">


 </div></div><div class="clear"></div>


 <?php 

  }
  }
 else
  {
 echo "No Result Found";
 }
 ?>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"  onClick="javascript:send_email();"><span>Send  Email</span></a>

 </div>
 </div>
 <div>
```

only just add jquery file in head section.

Comment: How have you tried it so far?  What code is not working?  Or do you expect us to write your entire solution for you?

Comment: i already write php mail function and its work for single user.

Comment: foreach($db->users as $user){ $to = $user->mailAddress; // code here }

Comment: Please don't cross post. I see you posted this question on Stackexchange [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26249758/3249111)

Comment: But not getting right answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a cross-post. Cross-posting is forbidden, if you feel you posted in wrong place, you should delete or ask for migration.

Comment: It appears that you are using the Drupal framework in an unorthodox way. This might work but you should read Drupal documentation instead: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/develop.

Comment: Please be patient when asking questions. Reposting the same quesion, and cross-posting the same question, because you didn't get an answer is not productive.

Comment: A better question for this drupal related site would be how can I properly integrate this code with a drupal site, and then also explain where you want this code to go. For example, what form is being submitted. The current code is not a good example of custom Drupal code because it does not follow any of the drupal code conventions.

Comment: Is there a reason your checkbox elements are not inside the form element? The checkbox name checkbox[] is strange. You have a while loop creating multiple checkboxes with the same id. Your mail function is hard coding the to address instead of using anything relating to the lawyer checkboxes. There are a bunch of problems so it's probably better to split it up into multiple questions, like how to implement a form with a dynamic amount of checkboxes, how to access checkbox values submitted from form post, how to make a form post back to the same page, etc. ...

Comment: ... When you break down into smaller questions and then do some seaching you find they are probably mostly answered already elsewhere. As the question currently stands, for someone to answer it they basically have to rewrite the code for you as there are too many separate aspects to it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only marginally about Drupal. It is more about using a Drupal function in code that is not written to be used in Drupal.

Comment: To make it clearer: Your code is not even using the form API, it's not clear in which context you would be using it (a template file, a module, a theme?), and it is not even code you would wrote for a theme or a module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function send_email(){
 var persons_names;
 persons_names = $('#send_mail_persons input:checked');
 var persons_names_Str='',coma='';
 if(persons_names.length != 0){
 persons_names.each(function(){
     persons_names_Str += coma+$(this).val();
     coma = ',';
 })
 }
 alert(persons_names_Str);
 //    console.log(" persons_names_Str: "+persons_names_Str);
 ajax_call_to_send_values_to(persons_names_Str);
 }


 function ajax_call_to_send_values_to(persons_names_Str){
 $.ajax({
              url: 'http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];? >',
            type: 'POST',
              data: { persons_names_Str: persons_names_Str            
                       },  
              success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {

              },
            //called when successful

              error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //called when there is an error
                  }
    });
 }
 </script>

 <?php
 if( isset($_POST['persons_names_Str']) && !empty($_POST['persons_names_Str']) )
  {
 $list = $_POST['persons_names_Str'];
 //print_r($list);
 //$to_arr = explode(",", $list);
 //$to = array_filter($to_arr);
 //echo $to;
 //print_r($to);
 $to = $list;
 $subject = "Test Subject";
 $body = "This is temporary email from Lawandmoney. ";
 $headers = "From: no-reply@lawandmoney.com\r\n" .
 "X-Mailer: php";

 $to =  "no-reply@lawandmoney.com";
 $headerFields = array('BCC: '.$list.', "From: no-reply@lawandmoney.com" ."X-Mailer:    php"');
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headerFields))) {
 //if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  echo("<p>Message sent successfully! our lawyer will contact you as soon as   possible</p>");
  } else {
  echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
  exit();
  }  

  ?>

  <div id="send_mail_persons">
  <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM lawyer_details WHERE city LIKE :city AND speciality LIKE   :speciality";
   $result = db_query($sql,array(':city' => '%'.  db_like($_SESSION['selected_county']).'%' , ':speciality' =>  '%'.db_like($_SESSION['lawarea']).'%'));

 $rows_count=$result->rowCount();

 if($result && $rows_count>0) 
 { 
 while($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) 
 {
  ?>
  <div class="result">
   <div class="resultPadder">
       <div class="resultLeft">
          <div id="fav">
         <div><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" id="email1" value=<?php echo  $row['email_id'];?> /><a class="b ui-link" href="" onclick=""><?php echo  $row['first_name'].' '.$row['middle_name'].' '.$row['last_name'];?></a>  
          </div>
       <div class="p-t-2"><?php echo $row['street_address'];?></div>
       </div>
       </div>
  <div class="resultRight">


 </div></div><div class="clear"></div>


 <?php 

  }
  }
 else
  {
 echo "No Result Found";
 }
 ?>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);"  onClick="javascript:send_email();"><span>Send  Email</span></a>

 </div>
 </div>
 <div>
```

only just add jquery file in head section.

Answer (score 1):

"to" parameter in drupal_mail is a string. You can have as many receipent as you like in the the emails "to" string, provided they are separated by commas (",").
You can do like this

```
$to  = 'one@email.com, two@email.com, three@email.com';
drupal_mail('$module_name', $key, $to, language_default(), $params = array('username' => 'test'), $from = NULL, $send = TRUE);
```

You may check the documentation of [drupal_mail](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7).

Comment: i m fetching data from database so when i click on checkbox only those recipients gets  email.how i can create array to add those recipients into array on click of checkbox