# how to get logged in username in email body

Tags: views

```
<?php 
$to="syz@abc.com";
$headers = "From: no-reply@xyz\r\n" ."X-Mailer: php";
$message="Dear Xyz, i am ".i write a following code here to get current username.";
$subject="Testing";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
echo("<p>Message sent successfully! our lawyer will contact you as soon as    possible</p>");
} else {
 echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
exit();
}
<?php global $user; //decl var
if ($user->uid) : //assing
print l($user->name,'user/'.$user->uid); //name output
else :
print l("Login","user"); //if not login this condition
endif;?>
```

i write following code in message body after saving code my contain disappeared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the working version of your code.

```
<?php
  global $user;
  if ($user->uid) {
    $test = l($user->name,'user/'.$user->uid); 
  } else {
    $test = l("Login","user");
  }
  echo $message="Dear Xyz, i am ". $test . " I write a following code here to get current username.";
?>
```

Comment: after this code mail is not sent. when i remove this code email work properly.

Comment: In which file you are writing this code?

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131253

Comment: in email body i want to display current logged in user name $body="current user name";

Comment: Just add following code and try to send email.

 <?php 
   global $user;
   if ($user->uid) {
    echo $user->name
}
?>

Comment: after pasting code data disappeared.

Comment: You are writing this code in a drupal module which is placed at sites/all/modules/[your_module] directory. Correct?

Comment: u can see code here drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131253. in $body i want to send logged in user details like name, email_id and contact number.

Answer (score 0):

Question is not really clear to me but if you want to add the username in massage then here is the way:-

```
<?php 

    $user=user_load($uid);
    $message = "Dear Xyz, i am ".$user->name.";
    print $message;
 ?>
```

Hope This Help!